# Switching layout XML in SherlockFragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I have a system of actionbar Tabs with ABS. The first tab is a login tab. I store the logged in user in a local SQLite db and a web SQL db. When the user hits the loginButton and the Async loginTask completes, I'd like to change the login tab's xml layout.

So basically I can run a test to see if the user is logged in, and if so use a new layout. **Is there any reasonable way to complete the layout switch in a SherlockFragment that resides in a system of actionBar tabs?**

Obviously I would need to run the same checks inside of onResume as well to make sure if the user is logged in, the right UI shows up. My problem there is a currently inflate my layout inside onCreateView, which doesn't rerun.

Here's some code:

```
public class LoginFragment extends SherlockFragment {
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    userFunctions = new UserFunctions();
//test ive made that has no effect since onCreateView only runs once.
    if(userFunctions.isUserLoggedIn(activity.getApplicationContext())) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.loggedin, container, false);
        return v;
    } else {//standard method when I didnt use the above test
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.loginfragment, container, false);
    return v;
    }
}
```

I have an activity that hosts the tabs etc, here's its relevant code:

```
public static class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
implements ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    private final Context mContext;
    private final ActionBar mActionBar;
    private final ViewPager mViewPager;
    private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();

    static final class TabInfo {
        private final Class<?> clss;
        private final Bundle args;

        TabInfo(Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
            clss = _class;
            args = _args;
        }
    }
    /*Constructor method that adds a TabsAdapter to each tab that is created.
     * It also adds the ViewPager to each tab so that the user can swipe to change tabs.
     */
    public TabsAdapter(SherlockFragmentActivity activity, ViewPager pager) {
        super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
        mContext = activity;
        mActionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
        mViewPager = pager;
        mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }
    /*A fairly simple method that sets the TabInfo for each tab so that the TabsAdapter
     * knows which class the tab that is being added actually belonds to. It also updates
     * the UI interface when each tab is added. 
     */
    public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {
        TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
        tab.setTag(info);
        tab.setTabListener(this);
        mTabs.add(info);
        mActionBar.addTab(tab);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mTabs.size();
    }
    /*A method that is used in other classes to allow each tab Fragment to 
     * access its inherited methods from a mother-class, in this case, SherlockFragment
     */
    public SherlockFragment getItem(int position) {
        TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
        return (SherlockFragment)Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);
    }
    /*This method reads the user's selection for a new tab and sets that tab as
     * the new current focus.*/
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
    }
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}
    /* This is the method that actually draws the newest tab onto the screen when
     * it is selected.*/
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        Object tag = tab.getTag();
        for (int i=0; i<mTabs.size(); i++) {
            if (mTabs.get(i) == tag) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
            }
        }
    }
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {}
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {}
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {}
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your fragment layout, you can use a [ViewSwitcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewSwitcher.html) to switch between two views, one for the login, and another one for the info you want to show when the user is logged.

Comment: I am still fine tuning the app persistence aspects of this (when I need to redo showNext() etc) but this system is very simple, quite elegant in implementation (not complex) and straightforward. I also had never seen it before, so bounty definitely earned.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps my solution would be oversimplified but I have something going on like that in one of my Activities and as far as I can tell I'm not taking a huge performance hit.  Here's what I do.

I place all the xml items in a single layout .xml file.  Make the RelativeLayout your parent layout then create two layouts within the RelativeLayout.  One containing the xml from your **R.layout.loggedin** and the other layout containing the **R.layout.loginfragment** xml items.  I then, on onActivityCreated would make the following call.

```
if(userFunctions.isUserLoggedIn(activity.getApplicationContext())) {
   loginfragment.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.GONE);
   //Your other appropriate code here to interact with the items in this layout
} else {//standard method when I didnt use the above test
    loggedin.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.GONE);
   //More code here to interact with the items in this layout
}
```

I have my TabsAdapter class equivalent in set to

```
 android:stateNotNeeded="true"
```

in my AndroidManifest.xml.  This enables me to launch an activity write to the db and when I come back the appropriate change is made because the screen is redrawn.  With this approach, though I'm not sure why you would do it, you could even call for the changes in the xml repeatedly within the activity as much as you want.

I use this successfully in an Activity that I have and it works swimmingly.  Hope this helps!